# The circumference of the circle is $C$, what is the area of circle in terms of $C$?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, circles, area

The circumference of the circle is $C$, what is the area of circle in terms of $C$?

a). $\dfrac {C^2}{4\pi }$

b). $2\pi C$

c). $\dfrac {4}{3} \pi C^2$

d). $2\pi C^2$

My Attempt:
$$\textrm {Circumference}=2\pi r$$
$$C=2\pi r$$
$$\dfrac {C}{2\pi }= r$$
Now,
 Area$=\pi r^2$
$$=\pi \dfrac {C^2}{4\pi^2}$$

Comment: Well, this is indeed right. Now you can cancel out the $\pi$ in the numerator with one in the denominator and arrive at the answer.

Comment: If one wanted to do this without algebra, one can note that (1) $C$ is a length and $A$ is an area, so $A$ should be some multiple of $C^2$, and (2) when $r=1$ you've got $C^2=4\pi^2$ and $A=\pi=C^2/(4\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct, you should just cancel out the $\pi$ in the expression:

$$\require{cancel} \dfrac {\pi C^2}{4\pi^2} = \dfrac {\bcancel{\pi} C^2}{4 \bcancel{\pi} \pi} = \dfrac {C^2}{4\pi}$$